# Create discrete colorbar

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, colormap

I am trying to create a colormap from an image. This works fine using a continuous range but I'm trying to reduce the amount of colors by a discrete factor.

I have tried to do this using 10 colors via the following code but all I get is red?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import numpy as np

cim = plt.imread("https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q2Ev.png")
cim = cim[cim.shape[0]//2, 8:740, :]

cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(cim)
norm = mcolors.BoundaryNorm([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], cmap.N)

X = np.random.rand(10,10)
Y = np.random.rand(10,10)

plt.contourf(X, Y, levels=100, cmap=cmap, norm = norm)# alpha = 0.8)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't the image data between 0 and 1? You will see a difference when you multiply data by 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want 10 colors in your colormap, you can create it with just those 10 colors:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import numpy as np

cim = plt.imread("https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q2Ev.png")
cim = cim[cim.shape[0]//2, 8:740, :]
cim_10 = cim[cim.shape[0] // 9 * np.arange(10)]  # array of 10 colors

cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap(cim_10)
print(cmap.N)    # prints 10

X = np.random.rand(10,10)

plt.contourf(X, cmap=cmap, levels=np.linspace(0, 1, 11))
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

[image]